# Drupal 7.3 ajax error - am not able to create views

Tags: ajax, drupal, view

I am using Drupa 7.3 and am not able to create views on which i get the following error.

An AJAX HTTP error occurred.HTTP Result Code: 200Debugging information follows.Path: /drupal/system/ajaxStatusText: OKResponseText: z[ {"command":"settings", "settings":{"basePath":"\u002Fdrupal\u002F", "pathPrefix":"", "ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seven", "theme_token":"Y_yqvbgRwL0BAM25F5tUf7vNb0WwAECTyEToD0yz008", "jquery_version":"1.10", "css":{"misc\u002Fui\u002Fjquery.ui.core.css":1, "misc\u002Fui\u002Fjquery.ui.theme.css":1, "modules\u002Foverlay\u002Foverlay-parent.css":1}, "js":{"sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fjquery_update\u002Freplace\u002Fui\u002Fui\u002Fminified\u002Fjquery.ui.core.min.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fjquery_update\u002Freplace\u002Fmisc\u002F1.9\u002Fjquery.ba-bbq.min.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fjquery_update\u002Freplace\u002Fmisc\u002F1.9\u002Foverlay-parent.js":1}}, "overlay":{"paths":{"admin":"node\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fdelete\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u002F*\u002Frevert\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u002F*\u002Fdelete\u000Anode\u002Fadd\u000Anode\u002Fadd\u002F*\u000Aoverlay\u002Fdismiss-message\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fshortcuts\u000Aadmin\u000Aadmin\u002F*\u000Abatch\u000Ataxonomy\u002Fterm\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fcancel\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fedit\u002F*", "non_admin":"admin\u002Fstructure\u002Fblock\u002Fdemo\u002F*\u000Aadmin\u002Freports\u002Fstatus\u002Fphp"}, "pathPrefixes":[  ], "ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"}, "a...-feed-properties-path\u0022\u003E\u000A  \u003Clabel for=\u0022edit-page-feed-properties-path--2\u0022\u003EFeed path \u003C\u002Flabel\u003E\u000A \u003Cspan class=\u0022field-prefix\u0022\u003Ehttp:\u002F\u002Fwww.lemonfuel.com\u002Fdrupal\u002F\u003C\u002Fspan\u003E \u003Cinput type=\u0022text\u0022 id=\u0022edit-page-feed-properties-path--2\u0022 name=\u0022page[feed_properties][path]\u0022 value=\u0022dfsdds.xml\u0022 size=\u002260\u0022 maxlength=\u0022128\u0022 class=\u0022form-text\u0022 \u002F\u003E\u000A\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u000A\u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-page-feed-properties-row-plugin-wrapper\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-select form-item-page-feed-properties-row-plugin\u0022\u003E\u000A  \u003Clabel for=\u0022edit-page-feed-properties-row-plugin--2\u0022\u003EFeed row style \u003C\u002Flabel\u003E\u000A \u003Cselect id=\u0022edit-page-feed-properties-row-plugin--2\u0022 name=\u0022page[feed_properties][row_plugin]\u0022 class=\u0022form-select\u0022\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022node_rss\u0022 selected=\u0022selected\u0022\u003EContent\u003C\u002Foption\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022rss_fields\u0022\u003EFields\u003C\u002Foption\u003E\u003C\u002Fselect\u003E\u000A\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u000A\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E", "settings":null}, {"command":"insert", "method":"prepend", "selector":null, "data":"", "settings":null} ]

Comment: You need to give us more information. A quick googl search reaveals you may be using the "System Status Ajax" module.

Comment: Oh,BTW, If you are still on Drupal 7.3, you site has almost certainly been hacked https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005